# Jquery - how to Remove content of div (but dynamically based on clicked row)

Tags: jquery

I have a table with Rows. And i have a soccer field  div with 
Child DIVs for each player!

When i Click on a Row, i have a JQuery Funktion who adds The player into My Field (with a playerID)! After That the picked player is greyed out!

But now  i want to remove the player from the Field (dynamically Based on His ID) when i am clicking again on the grey row!

How could i so do something like this without selecting by a Static selector like

```
$("#goalkeeper").empty();
```

Here is My fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qcvcga8k/30/

Thx for alllll hints ;)

Alex

Comment: Can you post HTML

Comment: Please post some code. But you could save the playerID in the row as an data-attribute so you know which player belongs to this row

Comment: $("#remove").remove();

Comment: Fiddle please ?

Comment: @AakashThakur: Here is my fiddle: thx for helping ;)
https://jsfiddle.net/qcvcga8k/32/